# WebChat in sharepoint getting postback

Tags: sharepoint, botframework

WebChat in sharepoint getting postback. Added web part in sharepoint and trying to implement webchat.

Whenever I hit enter or send button it gives a postback. How can we avoid postback when events occur (eg:button click)?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      var jq = $.noConflict();

      jq(document).ready(function () {

      try {

      BotChat.App({
      directLine: {
      secret: 'Qc--iFxcebI.cwA.poU.XfmiUiUHwK9AjLZXzUoA_ewI3s6fktbN447HI9qVqLE'
      },
      user: {
      id: _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName //_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName
      },
      bot: {
      id: 'botid'
      },
      sendTyping: true,
      resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));

      } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      }

      try {
      jq('.wc-header > span').html('Search Bot');
      jq(".wc-header").click(function () {
      jq(".botcontainer").toggleClass("height");
      });
      } catch (e) {
      debugger;
      console.log(e.message);
      }

      });
    </script>

    <div class="botcontainer ms-dialogHidden ms-fullWidth noindex" id="bot" ></div>
```

Comment: Previous similar issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/594

Comment: hi eric thanks for replying ... but i dont have a button of my button ... it is from the botchat.js and botchat.css

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, create an aspx page in the page library and add HTML code in the page to achieve webchat. Then add a iframe in a script editor web part.

```
<iframe id="botchat" src="/chatbot/Pages/chatbot.aspx?t=<directline secret>" width="320" height="500"></iframe>
```

Similar thread:
[Using WebChat in SharePoint Script Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/228)